# is it possible to use same oracle connector jar to all versions of oracle db?

Tags: oracle, connector

I am developing an generic java application for oracle db.my application should be connect with all versions of oracle db. in oracle site they have mentioned different connector jar files for different oracle DB version.

Is there any common connector available for oracle?

Answer (score 0):

There is compatibility matrix. Also there is recommended Java version that needs to be used with JDBC driver. I assume you use JDBC thin driver. 
If you use today 11.2 JDBC driver, you should be ok for any Oracle version starting from 9.0.1. 

So as starting point, take most appropriate driver for JDK and Oracle servers you use and keep an eye on documentation when new Oracle server comes out. Driver of the latest version can "buy" you more time as it would be longer supported than some old JDBC driver.

Some more info for 11.2 version can be found on http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/getsta.htm#i1008205

Comment: will the connector jar files be available if we install oracle DB? why asking this means we can ask the user to upload the drivers.

Comment: Yes, with Oracle server installation you get JDBC driver.